# Stubbing Github module for test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

In my gem i am using [Github](https://github.com/peter-murach/github) gem for GitHub API. I created a `EachValidator` for checking existency of some `URL` given:

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  return if value.empty? and not opts[:presence]
  if check_github_url value
    repo_data = GithubStats::Parser.parse value
    begin
      Github.repos(user: repo_data[:username], repo: repo_data[:repo]).commits.all
    rescue Github::Error::NotFound => e
  p e
      record.errors[attribute] << error_message
    end
  else
    record.errors[attribute] << error_message
  end
end
```

How to **stub** `Github.repos` method to return concrete values? Does change class for some stubbed (responding as I want) will be enough? I was using [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) but i can't figure it out how to use here.

### Edit:

I am considering:

```
# inside test class
def initialize
  Github.stubs(:repos).returns(what_i_want_to_put_here)
end
```

First thing is to *return good response or raise exception in condition of given params* so i need to catch parameters somehow. Or maybe should I *raise an exception of test case need it*? That would be perfect and simple solution but gives me nothing from testing, am I right?

### Edit 2:

I tried something like that:

```
#test case class
def initialize param
  Github.stubs(:repos).returns({})
  Github.repos.stubs(:commits).returns({})
  Github.repos.commits.stubs(:all).returns({})
  super param
end

def test_method
  Github.repos.commits.stubs(:all).throws(Github::Error::NotFound.new({}))
  # do the real method
  validated_record = validate_github_url("https://github.com/puradawid/github_stats_notexisting") do |model, attr_name|
    model.errors.[].expects('<<').once
  end
end
```

But it is throwing an exception:

```
ArgumentError: uncaught throw #<Github::Error::NotFound:  :  >
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/thrower.rb:10:in `throw'
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/thrower.rb:10:in `evaluate'
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/return_values.rb:20:in `next'
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/expectation.rb:569:in `invoke'
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/mock.rb:296:in `method_missing'
    /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mocha-1.1.0/lib/mocha/class_method.rb:63:in `all'
    /home/dawid/github_stats/lib/validators/github_projects_url_validator.rb:8:in `validate_each'
    /home/dawid/github_stats/test/github_validator_test.rb:85:in `validate_github_url'
    /home/dawid/github_stats/test/github_validator_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:GithubStatsValidatorTest>'
```

Look at the first code here. It is catching `Github::Error:NotFound` so what is the problem with the code here?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Github.expects(:repos).returns(JSON.generate("Some Return Value"))
```

So assuming you are expecting the API to return JSON you could do

```
require 'json'

...

Github.expects(:repos).returns(JSON.generate({some: :hash}))
```

Comment: That is a pretty good idea, unfortunately won't work - it's not a JSON as you can see, `Github::API` is far more sophisticated object (using `Hashie` and a lot of metaprogramming though). I am still looking for the best idea for mocking this gem.